# Мониторинг работы в приложении android

Tags: android

Доброго времени суток. Можно ли с помощью средств андроида получить название приложения в котором работает юзер и время работы в этом приложении. то есть сервис будет получать имя приложения и время сеанса и посылать в базу.

Нашел решение без рута

```
 private String getRunningAppByActivity(){
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)             context.getSystemService(context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        // get the info from the currently running task
        List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);

        ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
        String name=componentInfo.getPackageName();

        final PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        ApplicationInfo ai;
        try {
            ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(name, 0);
        } catch (final PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            ai = null;
        }
        final String applicationName = (String) (ai != null ? pm.getApplicationLabel(ai) : "(unknown)");
        Log.d("APPLICATION_NAME", applicationName);
        return applicationName;
    }
```

Comment: Информацию вы планируете получать о своем приложении или о сторонних?

Comment: о всех. Есть у гугла в настройках возможность посмотреть расход батареи для всех приложений и также показывается время работы, значит скорее всего - как-то это можно реализовать. Меня интересует только название активного приложения и время сеанса

Answer (score 2):

Платформа Android так уж устроена, чтобы приложения как можно меньше "лезли" друг к другу, не мешая тем самым. Так, каждое приложение находится в своей "песочнице"( сопоставим это, с собственной директорией приложения в `/data/data` ), у каждого процесса( читайте, приложения ) свой пользователь( и в большинстве случаев уникальный ) и т.д.

То, что вы ответили на мой комментарий выше, поясню: этим мониторингом занимается системный сервис, "корни" которого уходят в более низкий слой [Android-абстракции](http://androidlessons.tumblr.com/post/241639413/android-software-stack). Соответственно, обладая куда большими полномочиями, чем простое стороннее приложение и сторонний сервис.

Вы можете решить свою задачу, задействуя, например, механизм суперпользователя( SU, ROOT, S-OFF - кому как нравится ), используя  *nix утилиту **SU**, которая находится в рутированном устройстве всегда по умолчанию( обычно лежит где-то здесь: **/system/xbin** ).
Вот пример получения списка запущенных процессов:

```
try{
    Runtime.getRunTime().exec( new String[]{ "su", "-c", "ps -e" } )
}catch(Exception e){ }
```

Соответственно, зная Linux Shell и имея рутированный девайс, перед вами открываются практически безграничные возможности :)

Comment: то есть получается, что если у пользователя не рутованый девайс, то я не смогу ничего сделать?

Comment: Рутированные девайсы сейчас у большого числа людей: массы понимают, что через рут им открываются некоторые "кульные" возможности через приложения, вроде этого, например.

---
Такая ситуация сложилась и потому, что слово "рут" нынче культивировано куда более, чем раньше. Порой люди получают рут, даже не зная зачем. И все благодаря относительно мягкой политике производителей мобильных устройств, выпуску тонны приложений для быстрого и простого рутирования и т.д и т.п

Comment: я написал в теме одно из найденных решений, но еще его не тестил

Comment: @0xFFh большая часть людей с Android даже не знаю, что такое "рут" вообще. Так что, не надо дезинформировать )

Comment: @Suvitruf, та большая часть, вероятнее всего, сидит на IOS )
Android - платформа для моддинга, персонализа..
80% от 50% активных Android пользователей не только знают, но и имеют рут. Остальные же 50% всей Android "аудитории" вряд ли вообще нуждается в чем-то стороннем, кроме игр, наверное..

Comment: @0xFFh честно, не пойму откуда у вас такая инфа. Если юзер не разработчик, то он максимум на что спосоебн - качнуть пиратки с 4pda. У меня даже на работе php/Java/etc разработчики, не пишущие под Android, ходят с нерутованными телефонами

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать сервис, который следить будет за запусками приложений и посылать в базу инфу.

Можно сделать BroadcastReceiver, который будет прослушивать запуск Intent'ов и писать в базу инфу.

Попробовать прочитать из LogCat'а  ActiviyManager'ера